# Application.Selection.Find.Execute() operates with text even outside the selection

Tags: c#, replace, ms-word, selection, word-addins

I am working on MS Word add-in, which is meant to convert selected text from latin to cyrillic. Here's the method:

```
public void L_to_C_Text_Convert()
    {
        //
        string[] latin =
            {"a","b","v","g","dž","d","đ","e","ž","z","i","k","lj","l","m","nj","n","j","o","p","r","s","t","ć","u","f","h","c","č","š"};
        //
        string[] cyrillic =
            {"а","б","в","г","џ","д","ђ","е","ж","з","и","к","љ","л","м","њ","н","ј","о","п","р","с","т","ћ","у","ф","х","ц","ч","ш"};
        //
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            Application.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting();
            Application.Selection.Find.Text = latin[i];
            //
            Application.Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting();
            Application.Selection.Find.Replacement.Text = cyrillic[i];
            //
            object replaceAll = Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
            //
            Application.Selection.Find.Execute(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                    ref replaceAll, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
        }
    }
```

It mostly works fine, but sometimes it acts strange. When only one letter is selected, the program replaces all letters (like selected one) outside the selection as well as that exact letter inside the selection, what, of course, I don't want or need. It sometimes does that even with random (seems like random) letters, outside the selection.

When debugging, I had Application.Selection.Text on Watch and that made me to even more don't have a clue what's wrong.

Why does it work like that and what should I do to prevent that replacing outside the selection?

Answer (score 0):

If the value you search for exactly matches the current search range, Word will assume it is the result of having just found it (when a match is found, the search range is changed to the range of the match) and will therefore dynamically change the search range to the content before or after (depending on settings) the current search range. Without this behaviour, every time you search for the next match, the search range wouldn’t change because it already completely contains the value you are searching for.

When you perform a Find and Replace, it’s the same thing. If the value you are searching for exactly matches the current search range, Word will change the search range, and if the value of the Replace property is 2 (WdReplaceAll) then the current search range is included in the new search range.

With this in mind, to prevent the replacing outside the selection in those cases where the current selection is exactly one of the values you are searching for, you could add some code at the start of your For loop which checks to see if the current selection is equal to `latin[i]` and, if it is equal to `latin[i]`, replace the value with `cyrillic[i]` and then exit the For loop.